# ssh client not connecting through public ip

Tags: networking, ssh

I have set up ssh server on my Raspberry pi and forwarded 22 port on router to it. I can connect to it via local network just fine, my friend could also connect to it from his home. However, when I try

```
ssh pi@my.router.ip.address -v
```

where `my.router.ip.address` is external address of my router, I get

```
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to XX.XX.XX.XX [XX.XX.XX.XX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/julka/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/julka/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.3
```

The last line hangs untill I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it, independently if I allow password authentication or not. My `~/.ssh.` contents:

```
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (no user config)

```
Host *
ForwardX11Trusted yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
HashKnownHosts yes
```

What of the most basic things am I missing that I cannot ssh into my Raspi?

I even tried creating `julka` account on my ssh server as per @darent suggestion.

EDIT:

Pi's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config/` (commented lines skipped):

```
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: For some reason, it's trying to authenticate with your user keys (julka, not pi) and I'm not sure, but that may be the problem. It looks in the server for such user and it doesn't exists. Try forcing the server to prompt you for a password with this: ssh -v -o PreferredAuthentications=password pi@my.router.ip.address And post the output here.

Comment: Does the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` of the client is the relevant public key for the Pi server's private key `~/id/rsa` ?

Comment: I copied my public key alright, if that's what you re asking. I can connect without typing password through local network.

Comment: Can you please post more lines of the debug log? It says the connection is established but the really interesting things happen after the point where you've truncated the output. Also what is the ip address of 'my.router'; is it the internal or the external address?

Comment: @wie5Ooma That's all there is to it, external address.

Comment: Did you try to connect from a different Internet access (or through VPN)? Connecting to your own external IP from your internal LAN may have some strange effects. The fact, that there is a connection would speak against this but it's worth a try

Comment: @Germar Haven't thought about that, you were right. Feel free to add as answer - I could connect from other network. Why do I have to use local addresses in local networks? ( Rethorical question)

Comment: @julka I've no idea what causes this. I just experienced this by my self.

Comment: I've a different experience. I can connect to my own external IP address from anywhere and from any device capble of SSH that I own. I only did switch off the DNS capabilities of SSH which is not used any way while SSH-ing to an IP address, so apparently it can be done without problems, or I'm just lucky or maybe I've changed something unrelated that makes it possible. We'll probably never know...  ;-)

Comment: @wie5Ooma I didn't try to switch off DNS cappabilities yet. Could be a reason. But it could also depend on your ISP and their routing. Who knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to your own external IP from inside your LAN may have some strange effects. You should try to connect from an other external Internet access (e.g. mobile or through VPN).

<sub>This is the answer from my comment above.</sub>